# Angular and Ionic-v4 ion-select popover is not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic4

I would like to open ionSelect programmatically with the popover mode.

```
@ViewChild('selectNotificationList') selectNotificationList: IonSelect;
```

the methods for open a ion-select is:

```
clickNotificationNumber() {
    this.selectNotificationList.interface = 'popover';
    this.selectNotificationList.open();
}
```

The HTML is:

```
<ion-card slot="end" class="langCard">
    <ion-card-content>
        <ion-select interface ="popover"  (ionChange)="readNotification($event)" #selectNotificationList>
            <ion-select-option *ngFor="let message of notificationList let notificationIndex = index"  value="{{message.id}}">
                {{message.notificationOptions.body}}</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;tr** Your approach works, just pass the mouse event along to get the popover instead of an alert. 
(tested with Angular 6.1.7 and Ionic 4.7.4)

---

I build a little mock app to test this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-fhcnzr

Clicking the button opens the select with interface="alert" though...

Turns out, the console tells you everything:

```
Select interface cannot be a "popover" without passing an event. 
Using the "alert" interface instead
```

After passing the click event from the button along...

```
clickNotificationNumber(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.selectNotificationList.interface = 'popover';
    this.selectNotificationList.open(event);
}
```

...the popover appeared beside the mouse as expected.